# Custom Post Type displays post belong on the category

Tags: php, custom-post-type, wordpress, wp-list-categories

I have a custom post type `advice` and taxonomy `adcat`. I want to display all post belong to that category.

Lets say I have 4 categories namely : 'games', 'tours', 'dishes', 'hotels' and also this four category is a menu. If I click one of the category for example: hotels all post belong to the hotels should display.

By the way this code I used to show wordpress default categories:

```
<?php $catname = wp_title('', false); ?>
<?php $posts = get_posts("category_name=$catname&numberposts=8&offset=0");
foreach ($posts as $post) : start_wp(); ?>

//html output
<h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>

<?php endforeach; ?>
```

this is not working in custom post 'taxonomies' any suggestion would be helpful thank's

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this maybe it work... I write a note so you can see whats going on.. hope it help

```
<?php
    // Get the term/category of the post
    $terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID , 'advice-cat' );
     foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
     $term_link = get_term_link( $term, 'advice cat' );
    }
    //WordPress loop for custom post type
    $terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID , 'advice-cat' );
     $my_query = new WP_Query('post_type=advice&advice-cat=' . $term->name . '&posts_per_page=-1');
          while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post(); ?>

     // output content

     <?php the_title(); ?>           


    <?php endwhile;  wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

try something like this, this is the example to fetch post by category id

```
$args = array( 'cat' => $cat_id, 'post_type' => 'advice', 'posts_per_page' => -1 );
    $loop = new WP_Query( $args );      
    while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
         the_title();
    endwhile; 
wp_reset_postdata();
```

you can also use with category name as well.

```
$args = array('category_name' => 'catname', 'post_type' => 'advice', 'posts_per_page' => -1 );
```

you can use post_per_page as per your requirement, I have just added -1 for all the posts

Comment: thank's for your answer but it display all post belong to advice not by category.

Comment: in this case you have to get the category name or category id and pass in argument to get the posts of specific category.

Answer (score 1):

I don't really understand your terminology. When you are talking about `adcat`, is it a custom taxonomy or a term of the build-in taxonomy `category`. If `adcat` is a custom taxonomy, you should use the `tax_query` in [`WP_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query),not the category parameters.

Remember, category and a custom taxonomy are both taxonomies, their direct children is called terms, and their direct childen is called child terms

You should also not be using `wp_title()` to get the queries object. You should be using `get_query_var()` to get the queried object. For categories it will be `cat`, taxonomy will be `taxonomy` and for terms `term`. Have a look at [`get_categories`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_categories), [`get_taxonomies`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_taxonomies) and [`get_terms`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_terms) for returned values

Example

```
$category = get_query_var( `cat` );
$cat_slug = $category->slug;
```

You can now return `$cat_slug` to your custom query as `category_name`

**EDIT**

I've quickly rethinked the whole thing and checked your comment as well. Why not just copy your index.php and rename it taxonomy.php. There is no need at all for a custom query here. The default loop in taxonomy.php should do it

**EDIT 2**

For further reading, go and check the following articles

- [Theme Development](http://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development)
- [Template Hierarchy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy)

Comment: adcat is my custom`'taxonomies`

Comment: Let me know if my solution works, and if it does, consider accepting my answer by clicking on the checkmark next to my answer

Comment: sure... but for now I just try to figure out how to implement your idea coz taking about php and wordpress, I'm new to this.. but anyway thank's for you suggestion this is also helpful for now..

Comment: No problem, the links I've supplied will definitely help you a lot. You should read them. Enjoy :-)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I read your answer correctly but what I am assuming is you want to search posts by the taxonomy terms correct? So in your `adcat` taxonomy you have 'games', 'tours', 'dishes', 'hotels' as your terms or categories. Your best option would be to use a `tax_query` in your query arguments. Here is how to do that with the WP_Query() object.

```
<?php 

$args = array( 
    'post_type' => 'advice',
    'posts_per_page' => 8,
    'tax_query' => array(
    'taxonomy' => 'adcat',
    'terms' => array('games', 'tours', 'dishes', 'hotels'),
    'field' => 'slug'
    )
);

$query = new WP_Query($args); 

if($query->have_posts()) : while($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post(); ?>

    <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>

<?php endwhile; endif; ?>
<?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

**Important Note:**
When using a WP_Query you will be overwriting the default post data. So in order to get that data back you just use the `wp_reset_postdata()` as you can see in the example above after the loop has finished.